# How to install linux-libc-dev in SliTaz (asm/ioctls.h)

Tags: slitaz

When I installed gcc from SliTaz repository tazPkg command.

I got

> gcc version 4.5.2 (SliTaz)

when I attempt to compile aircrack 1.2 beta on SliTaz.

I get a error with missing file (No such file or directory)

> asm/ioctls.h

from

> /usr/include/bits/ioctls.h:24:24: fatel error: asm/ioctls.h: No such
>   file or directory

It's included from

> /usr/include/sys/ioctl.h:27:0, from aircrack-ng.c:44:

After research I figured out I need the **linux-libc-dev** to fix this.

How do I get that? or anyone got aircrack 1.2 beta 1 working under SliTaz?

Comment: I haven't used slitaz in a while, but I believe tazpkg includes a tool to convert .deb files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did have a similar problem trying to build a newer version of Ruby. I am not mistaken glibc-dev should work, try: `sudo tazpkg -gi glibc-dev` That should get your build to work. If not tazpkg does have a convert tool for deb packages. `tazpkg convert deb-package-name`

Keep in mind that version 4 of Slitaz (the stable one) and 5 RC2 have more than a year apart in development so there packages lists will be different. Trying a newer version may also solve your problem or create new problems.